# cv2.seamlessClone() gives error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'Laplacian'

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use seamlessClone to blend a patch of a failure from one image *(marked with a mask)* onto another image. The images are gray-scale, when I try to call the function I get the following error and I can't pinpoint what is going wrong.

Code:

```
# Convert images to float32
image = np.array(image, dtype=np.float32)
image_with_fail = np.array(image_with_fail, dtype=np.float32)
image_with_fail_mask = np.array(image_with_fail_mask, dtype=np.uint8)*255

image = cv2.resize(image, (image_with_fail.shape[1], image_with_fail.shape[0]))
image = cv2.seamlessClone(image_with_fail, image, image_with_fail_mask, (143,143), cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)
```

This yields the following:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /Users/opencv-cn/GHA-OCV-1/_work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/deriv.cpp:792: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'Laplacian'
```

Any help is much appreciated!

I tried converting the images to 3 channels also, that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: The message says your source image is empty, so the error probably occurs before the code you show us when you read the image.

Comment: `dtype=np.float32` should be `dtype=np.unit8`

Comment: Thank you for the answers, changing the dtype didn't help unfortunately. Also the src image is not empty when I run: ```image_with_fail.shape ``` I get: (287, 289), I also checked by plotting the image itself using plt.imshow().

Comment: Try this `image_with_fail_mask = np.array(image_with_fail_mask, dtype=np.uint8)*255.0).astype("uint8")`

Comment: Thank you, did not seem to work however, I still the error from cv2 telling me the src image is empty. Do you think it could because the images are 2d and not 3d?